# EmberJS: initialize nested model with parent model loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I got the following simple ember.js-setup, which works all great

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('tourdates', function() {
        this.resource('tourdate', { path: ':tourdate_id' });
    });
});

App.TourdatesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return $.getJSON('http://someapi.com/?jsoncallback=?').then(function(data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
});

App.TourdateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return tourdates.findBy('id', params.tourdate_id);
    }
});
```

so, pretty simple, whenever i call index.html#/tourdates, i get the data via api. and when I click on a link in this view and call f.e. index.html#/tourdates/1 it just displays the view for its nested child.

This all breaks, when I directly call index.html#/tourdates/1 with the message

```
DEPRECATION: Action handlers contained in an `events` object are deprecated in favor of putting them in an `actions` object (error on <Ember.Route:ember174>)
Error while loading route: ReferenceError {} 
Uncaught ReferenceError: tourdates is not defined
```

Although he makes the ajax-call to the api and gets the data, he is not able to initialize the nested model

Answer (score 0):

When your `App.TourdatesRoute` is loaded, all data from the json, will be rendered. And when you click to edit one of these loaded objects, using a link-to for example, ember is smart enough to get the already referenced object, instead of send a new request. So your url will change to: `yourhost.com/tourdate/id`.

When you direct call this url, it will call the  `App.TourdateRoute` `model` method. Because doesn't have any pre loaded data. But in your case you have a:

```
tourdates.findBy('id', params.tourdate_id);
```

And I can't see in any place the declaration of `tourdates`.

I recommed you to change your `TourdateRoute` to `TourdateIndexRoute` so when transitioning to `tourdates` the ajax call is performed once:

```
App.TourdatesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return $.getJSON('http://someapi.com/?jsoncallback=?').then(function(data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
});
```

The `TourdatesRoute` is called both for `TourdateRoute` and `TourdatesIndexRoute`, because it's the parent route of both. So fetching all data in the `TourdatesIndexRoute` will ensure this is just called when transitioning to `tourdates`.

In your `TourdateRoute` you will load just the record needed. Something like this:

```
App.TourdateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        // retrieve just one data by id, from your endpoint
        return $.getJSON('http://someapi.com/' + params.tourdate_id + '?jsoncallback=?').then(function(data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
});
```

So a direct call to `yourhost.com/tourdate/id` will just loaded one record.

About your warning message, it happens because in some route you have:

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    eventA: function() { ...},
    eventB: function() { ...},
  }
});
```

The `events` is deprecated and you need to use `actions`:

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    eventA: function() { ...},
    eventB: function() { ...},
  }
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Your suggestions works, but why should I call the exact same API-request twice? All the details are already stored in the TourdatesRoute model. Is it not possible to get access to the TourdatesRoute-Model inside of the TourdateRoute-model ?

Comment: Hi @DavidSkx I have updated the answer to give more information. In the `TourdatesIndexRoute` you make an ajax to load all data, for example in a rest way: `yourhost/users` and in the `TourdateRoute` just for a record. Like `yourhost/users/3`.